# Where can i find "Shop By" file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

Where can I find the file that contains "Shop By" on the category pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in these files:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/navigation/left.phtml` 
`vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml`
`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml`